# GUI sftp client which uses .ssh/config settings

Tags: windows, sftp

I am used to making SSH settings via a standard ~/.ssh/config file; but in Linux/Unix we generally don't have that.

Now, I can use Cygwin's command-line SFTP client, but I'd like one that has a GUI.

Requirements:

- Gratis
- Uses either a Cygwin user's `.ssh/config` file, or an ssh client config file at an arbitrary location

Nice to have:

- Libre license
- Open source
- Behaves like WinScp...
- Not too "heavy"

Comment: `~/.ssh/config` is not really a configuration file for GUI clients. It does not define sessions in a way GUI clients do. It defines *defaults* for a specific host. It for instance does not allow you to define a multliple sessions to the same host (e.g. with a use of a different username).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: It's not a configuration file for GUI clients, it's a configuration file for making SSH connections, and I want its capabilities, i.e. not a small subset of them which the GUI client has enabled through its configuration dialogs.